# How to set a default field value in some form view in Odoo?

Tags: field, default-value, odoo-9, odoo, odoo-view

How to set default value in Job_id in this form with xml and don't need to set in the python file?

```xml
<record id="form_student_stu" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Student Info</field>
    <field name="model">youth_and_scholarship.youth_and_scholarship</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Job Form" version="9.0">
            <div class="widget_box">
                <div class="widget_title"><h5>Student Information</h5></div>
                <div>
                    <group col="1">
                        <field name="image" widget="image" class="oe_avatar oe_left" nolabel="1"/>
                        <field name="Job_id" invisible="1"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="Kname"  placeholder="First Name and Last Name..." string="Name in Khmer" style="width:40%%"/>
                        <field name="Ename" placeholder="First Name and last Name..." string="Name in Latin" style="width:40%%"/>
                        <field name="Gender" string="Gender" style="width:40%%"/>
                        <field name="DOB" string="Date of birth"/>
                        <field name="Job_work" string="Accupation" style="width:40%%"/>
                    </group>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some context specifying an XML ID (External ID). You can add the default value to the action which calls the view like this:

```xml
<record id="youth_and_scholarship_youth_and_scholarship_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Student Info</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">youth_and_scholarship.youth_and_scholarship</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_job_id': ref('xml_id')}</field>
</record>
```

If you open the view from a field, from a many2one for example, you can add the context to that field:

```xml
<field name="field_name" context="{'default_job_id': ref('xml_id')}" />
```

If haven't set the XML ID of the record you can get the ID by Python code and return an action window with the context:

```py
job_id = self.get_job_id()
return {
    'name': 'Student Info',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'res_model': 'youth_and_scholarship.youth_and_scholarship',
    'context': {'default_job_id': job_id }
}
```

**NOTES**:

- The key always has to be: `default_` + `field_name`: `database_id`
- You can see all the XML IDs here: **Settings > Technical > Sequences & Identifiers > External Identifiers > Complete ID**